# How to only show part of a partial in a particular view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I need to only show part of a partial in a view. I am loading the partial in other views and I don't want to load all of it.

What I've done and it broke my build was to set up a `ViewBag.Title = "cat"` in the view, then check in the partial `if(ViewBag.Title == "cat")`, show this bit of html.

I think what is wrong here is the fact that I am checking in the partial before the partial is actually used in the view..

Anyway, how should I approach this?

**Later edit:**

Category.cshtml:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Cat";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<p>some random html</p>
```

_Layout.cshtml

```
@if (ViewBag.Title == "Cat")
    {
      <span>html I need only in Category.cshtml</span>
    }
```

Comment: Both are in same controller context or different?

Comment: Show your view's (relevant) code and the actual compiler error.

Comment: updated; same controller I think, the partial is a simple cshtml file and I can't see any reference to it in any controllers

Comment: It's not reliable to depend on a string to do such view alterations. Think about using some sort of a state. Not sure about your circumstances, you might be able to use a Session variable that you set in your Action and you access it in your _Layout view

Answer (score 0):

I think you cannot access the ViewBag created in the other controller action method from other action.

```
public ActionResult Main()
{
  ViewBag.Title="Parent Page";
  return View();
}

public ActionResult Partial()
{
 return View();
}
```

Partial.cshtml // **ERROR**

```
if(ViewBag.Title)// should be null, since it is running in a different controller context
```

Please change the logic of checking the other controller context's view